# Java Game Error, NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, 2d-games

I have this issue with a game, a nullPointerException, it accrues only sometimes.
I'll put the code and if someone can help, that would help me a lot. I'll only put the code that I think it's important so if there is need for more i'll edit.
Thank you.

```
package wave.myFirstGameEver;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1550691097823471818L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private Random r;
    private Handler handler;
    private HUD hud;
    private Spawn spawner;
    private Menu menu;


    public enum STATE { // enum inside of our class, but we can do a different
                        // enum class like the ID class
        Menu, 
        Game,
        Help,
        End

    };

    public static STATE gameState = STATE.Menu; //changes the game's state to Menu or Game


    public Game() {

        handler = new Handler();
        hud = new HUD();
        menu = new Menu(this, handler, hud);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
        this.addMouseListener(menu);

        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Wave!", this);


        spawner = new Spawn(handler, hud);      
        r = new Random();

        if (gameState == STATE.Game) 
        {

            handler.addObject(new Player(WIDTH / 2 - 32, HEIGHT / 2 - 32, ID.Player, handler));
            handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH - 50), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT - 50), ID.BasicEnemy, handler));

        }else{
            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                handler.addObject(new MenuParticle(r.nextInt(WIDTH),r.nextInt(HEIGHT), ID.MenuParticle, handler));
            }


        }
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if (running)
                render();
            frames++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick() {
        handler.tick();

        if(gameState == STATE.Game) {

            hud.tick();
            spawner.tick();

            if(HUD.HEALTH <= 0){ //for the particle effect in the menu and at the end when u die
                HUD.HEALTH = 100;

                gameState = STATE.End;
                handler.clearEnemys();
                for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                    handler.addObject(new MenuParticle(r.nextInt(WIDTH),r.nextInt(HEIGHT), ID.MenuParticle, handler)); 
                }

            }

        }else if(gameState == STATE.Menu || gameState == STATE.End){
            menu.tick();
        }

    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        handler.render(g);

        if (gameState == STATE.Game) {

            hud.render(g);
        }else if(gameState == STATE.Menu || gameState == STATE.Help || gameState == STATE.End){
            menu.render(g);
        }

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static float clamp(float var, float min, float max) {
        if (var >= max)
            return var = max;
        else if (var < min)
            return var = min;
        else
            return var;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Game();
    }
}

package wave.myFirstGameEver;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public abstract class GameObject {
        protected float x,y;
        protected ID id;
        protected float velX, velY;
        public GameObject(float x, float y, ID id){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.id = id;
        }
        public abstract void tick();
        public abstract void render(Graphics g);
        public abstract Rectangle getBounds();
        public void setX(int x){
                this.x = x;
        }
        public void setY(int y){
                this.y = y;
        }
        public float getX(){
                return x;
        }
        public float getY(){
                return y;
        }
        public void setID(ID id){
                this.id = id;
        }
        public ID getId(){
                return id;
        }
        public void setVelX(int velX){
                this.velX = velX;
        }
        public void setVelY(int velY){
                this.velY = velY;
        }
        public float getVelX(){
                return velX;
        }
        public float getVelY(){
                return velY;
        }
}


package wave.myFirstGameEver;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import wave.myFirstGameEver.Game.STATE;

public class Menu extends MouseAdapter {

        private Game game;
        private Handler handler;
        private HUD hud;
        private Random r = new Random();


        public Menu(Game game, Handler handler, HUD hud){
            this.game = game;
            this.hud = hud;
            this.handler = handler;

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){ //when i press it stores what the x and y position is 
            int mx = e.getX();
            int my = e.getY();


            if(game.gameState == STATE.Menu){

                //play button
                if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 150, 200, 64)){
                    game.gameState = STATE.Game;

                    handler.addObject(new Player(Game.WIDTH / 2 - 32, Game.HEIGHT / 2 - 32, ID.Player, handler));
                    handler.clearEnemys();
                    handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH - 50), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT - 50), ID.BasicEnemy, handler));

                }

                //help button
                if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 250, 200, 64)){
                    game.gameState = STATE.Help;

                }

                //guit button 
                if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 350, 200, 64)){
                    System.exit(1);

            }

}
            //back button for help

            if(game.gameState == STATE.Help){
                if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 350, 200, 64)){
                    game.gameState = STATE.Menu;
                    return;
                }

            }

            //back button for end

            if(game.gameState == STATE.End){
                if(mouseOver(mx, my, 210, 350, 200, 64)){
                    game.gameState = STATE.Game;
                    hud.setLevel(1);
                    hud.setScore(0);
                    handler.addObject(new Player(Game.WIDTH / 2 - 32, Game.HEIGHT / 2 - 32, ID.Player, handler));
                    handler.clearEnemys();
                    handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH - 50), r.nextInt(Game.HEIGHT - 50), ID.BasicEnemy, handler));
                }

            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){


        }

        // this method is checking is the mouse is over a selectide target 
        private boolean mouseOver(int mx, int my, int x, int y, int width, int height){
            if(mx > x && mx < x + width){
                if(my > y && my < y + height){
                    return true;
                }else return false;
            }else return false;

        }

        public void tick(){


        }

        public void render(Graphics g){
            if(game.gameState == STATE.Menu){

                Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
                Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);

                g.setFont(fnt);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.drawString("Wave", 240, 70);

                g.setFont(fnt2);
                g.drawRect(210, 150, 200, 64);
                g.drawString("Play", 280, 190);


                g.drawRect(210, 250, 200, 64);
                g.drawString("Help", 280, 290);


                g.drawRect(210, 350, 200, 64);
                g.drawString("Quit", 280, 390);
            }else if(game.gameState == STATE.Help){

                Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
                Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);
                Font fnt3 = new Font("arial", 1, 20);


                g.setFont(fnt);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.drawString("Help", 240, 70);

                g.setFont(fnt3);
                g.drawString("Use WASD keys to move player and dodge enemies", 70, 200);

                g.setFont(fnt2);
                g.drawRect(210, 350, 200, 64);
                g.drawString("Back", 280, 390);
            }else if(game.gameState == STATE.End){

                Font fnt = new Font("arial", 1, 50);
                Font fnt2 = new Font("arial", 1, 30);
                Font fnt3 = new Font("arial", 1, 20);


                g.setFont(fnt);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.drawString("Game Over", 180, 70);

                g.setFont(fnt3);
                g.drawString("You lost with a score of: " + hud.getScore(), 170, 200);

                g.setFont(fnt2);
                g.drawRect(210, 350, 200, 64);
                g.drawString("Try Again", 245, 390);
            }



        }
}

package wave.myFirstGameEver;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.LinkedList;  this gives a nullPointer....90% of the cases, see later
public class Handler {
        ArrayList<GameObject> object = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
        public void tick(){
                for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
                        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);         
                        tempObject.tick();
                }
        }
        public void render(Graphics g){
                for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
                        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);         
                        tempObject.render(g);
                        }
        }

        public void clearEnemys(){ 
            for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
               GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

               if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player)
               {
                   object.clear();
                   if(Game.gameState != Game.STATE.End)
                   addObject(new Player((int)tempObject.getX(), (int)tempObject.getVelY(), ID.Player, this));


               }


                }

        }
        public void addObject(GameObject object){
                this.object.add(object);
        }
        public void removeObject(GameObject object){
                this.object.remove(object);
        }
}

package wave.myFirstGameEver;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class HUD {
        public static float HEALTH = 100;
        private float greenValue = 255;
        private int score = 0;
        private int level = 1;
        public void tick(){
                HEALTH = (int) Game.clamp(HEALTH, 0, 100);
                greenValue = (int) Game.clamp(greenValue, 0, 255);
                greenValue = HEALTH * 2;       
                score++;
        }
        public void render(Graphics g){
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
                g.fillRect(15, 15, 200, 32);
                g.setColor(new Color(75,(int) greenValue, 0));
                g.fillRect(15, 15,(int) HEALTH * 2, 32);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.drawRect(15, 15, 200, 32);
                g.drawString("Score: " + score, 15, 64);
                g.drawString("Level: " + level, 15, 80);       
        }
        public void setScore(int score){
                this.score = score;
        }
        public int getScore(){
                return score;
        }
        public int getLevel(){
                return level;
        }
        public void setLevel(int level){
                this.level = level;
        }
}
```

Comment: Negative 1 vote for posting a question about a problem, a NullPointerException, and demonstrating that you haven't searched the problem appropriately before asking. If you had, you would have known to post a stacktrace and to identify the offending line. Hoping for better questions in the future, and in that vein, please have a look at Jon Skeet's ["Stack Overflow question checklist"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) whicvh can be useful when you want to write good questions.

Comment: Please note that I'm not complaining about Java ignorance since none of us are born knowing Java, but I am complaining about lack of demonstrated effort. If you've done the searching beforehand, please show the results of these efforts with your questions.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels You're right!